# Dropdown on form isn't acting as required section

Tags: html

First off I'm a super noob to coding so sorry for that!

At my current job I've inherited some contact forms that were super heavy and caused a delay when loading a landing page for the first time. I've been trying to put together a cleaner version, which for the most part has gone fine, but the dropdown within the form isn't acting as a required field. The placeholder text reads 'State' which I've hidden as I want the user to be required to choose from the list below but when you submit the form without choosing anything the resulting email that comes through reads 'State: State'

Am I doing something completely wrong here? If anyone has any advice it's be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Iain

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic);
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact select,
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact {
  background: #FFFFF;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
}

#contact h3 {
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact select,
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact select:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 400 12px/16px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}

#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #CB0000;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #3A3A3A;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Contact Form</title>
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
   
   <div class="contact">
   <form id="contact" method="post" action="/forms/contact-form.php">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name: " type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
       <input name="email" placeholder="Email: " type="email" tabindex="2" required>
  <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone: " type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
       <input name="organisation" placeholder="Organisation: " type="text" tabindex="4" required>
  <input name="title" placeholder="Position Title: " type="text" tabindex="5" required>
  
    <select name="state" required tabindex="6"> 
                <option hidden="" value="State" disabled selected>State</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
     <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
     <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
                <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                <option value="NT">NT</option>
                </select>  
    
  <textarea placeholder="Message: " tabindex="7" required></textarea>
 
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
 </div>  

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use required attribute in HTML5 for select Tag. But remember, first value should be empty.

```
<select name="state" required>  
    <option value="" disabled hidden selected>State</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
    <option value="SA">SA</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not give any value to the state option to prevent the user to leave this select unspecified.

So remove value="state" like in the code line below:

`<option hidden="" value="" disabled selected>State</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Do not set value for `<option hidden="" value="State" disabled selected>State</option>`

make that value attribute empty.

```
<option hidden="" value="" disabled selected>State</option>
```

then only the required field work.

Answer (score 0):

With your HTML code, you must not put anything for `value` in the hidden, disabled, selected option. The `required` option best works if `value` is equal to nothing. Also, because it seems like you are using HTML5, you now have the ability to just put `hidden` by itself, similar to how you put `disabled` and `selected`. Thus, your HTML code could like something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="contact">
            <form id="contact" method="post" action="/forms/contact-form.php">
                <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name: " type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                <input name="email" placeholder="Email: " type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                <input name="phone" placeholder="Phone: " type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                <input name="organization" placeholder="Organization: " type="text" tabindex="4" required>
                <input name="title" placeholder="Position Title: " type="text" tabindex="5" required>
                <select name="state" tabindex="6" required> 
                    <option value="" disabled hidden selected>State</option>
                    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
                    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
                    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="SA">SA</option>
                    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
                    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
                    <option value="NT">NT</option>
                </select>
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message: " tabindex="7" required></textarea>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```